# Enabling view of Google data studio based on hierarchy

Tags: looker-studio

I have a Google data studio dashboard that I have created for all sales employees within my org. I have setup such that each user can view their performance data based on the **Filter by Email** setting in the data source tab.

I however am trying to see if I can have this configured such that each teams managers can also view their team members dashboard view. I am not sure if this can be configured or setup in Google Data Studio.

I have the data for this data studio dashboard rendered from a Google sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Good news, this is totally possible. Google has an article on how to set up a multiple email address filter, here is the link: [Filter by multiple email addresses per row](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9888200/filter-by-multiple-email-addresses-per-row). In summary, you should created an access control list (ACL) table which you can then blend with your underlying data in Google Data Studio.

For your specific use case, I'd recommend creating an additional sheet within your Google Spreadsheet that outlines various sales staff and their related managers to import into GDS.

Your ACL table could look something like this

| Access Email | Join Key |
| --- | --- |
| Manager@email | SalesRep1 |
| SalesRep1@email | SalesRep1 |
| Manager@email | SalesRep2 |
| SalesRep2@email | SalesRep2 |

Once the data is blended in GDS and your filter is updated, employees would be limited to their own data, while the manager would be able to access and view all employees under their purview.